# Raise to non-integer exponent in bash?

Tags: bash, math, floating-point

How to raise a number to a non-integer exponent in bash?

For example, this:

```
 echo $((10**0.25))
```

works in `zsh`, but in Bash it gives the following error:

> -bash: 10**0.25: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".25")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash supports only integer arithmetic. You have many alternatives, one of them is `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print 10**0.25}'
```

Comment: Sorry, I need a slightly more complicated example. I want to raise to a float that is stored in a variable `$x$`, and I want to assign the result to another variable, like `y = 10**$x`. How can I do this?

Comment: @becko: `y=$(awk "BEGIN {print 10**$x}")`, or slightly more robustly `y=$(awk -v "x=$x" 'BEGIN {print 10**x}')`

Answer (score 7):

The good old standby `bc` works as well

```
$ echo "e(0.25*l(10))" | bc -l
1.77827941003892280121
```

Comment: A very clever solution! I was not aware of the built-in natural log and exponential functions, but composing them to enable solving fractional powers is not immediately obvious but really cool.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic), Bash evaluates shell arithmetic in fixed-width integers. You need to use something more powerful, e.g. `perl`:

```
perl -e 'print 10**.25'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is `octave`:

```
octave --silent --eval '10 ^ 0.25'
```